# Refer to label in another chapter (another file)

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, thesis

I am writing my thesis using LyX's `thesis` template, and each chapter is a different file (`chapter-x.lyx`).

However, sometimes, I need to refer to a section from another chapter, which is in a different file. So for example:

**chapter-2.lyx**:

```
this is explained further in chapter \ref{chap:White-Box-Testing}
```

**chapter-3.lyx**:

```
\begin_layout Chapter
White Box Testing
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "chap:White-Box-Testing"
```

The problem is that when I generate the PDF document from Thesis.lyx, which has the pointers to all the `chapter-x.lyx` files, I get broken links in the output document.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you essentially trying to do this, or is it different? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628554/how-to-reference-a-figure-table-from-one-lyx-file-in-another-lyx-file

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor: I believe the questions are similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is solved by setting the correct "master document": In each branched document (`chapter-x.lyx`), go to `Document`>`Settings`>`Document Class`.
Here, ensure that `Select default master document` is checked and the value is set to the filename referring to the main document from which all these other documents branch off. In my case, this document is `Thesis.lyx` and not the default `thesis.lyx`.

This rename fixes the issue

Comment: Does this answer apply to this question as well? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628554/how-to-reference-a-figure-table-from-one-lyx-file-in-another-lyx-file

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor: I think it would apply

Comment: Do you think if I bounty the question, you could spare a few moments to show me how to get it to work?  This would be a really amazing thing to figure out, as most lyx users seem to think this is impossible.

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor I'd be happy to help. But I should note that it's been a while since I've written my thesis (and therefore used this feature). Please try the posted answer and if it doesn't work, shoot me an email and I'll be happy to help as best as I can