# How to reference a figure/table from one lyx file in another lyx file?

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I have two lyx files.

```
File1.lyx
```

and

```
File2.lyx.
```

I want to reference the pagenumber of the conclusion, for example, from `File2.lyx` in `File1.lyx`. When I insert cross-ref, it gives back Page `??` because of course these are separate documents.

Can this be done with [multidoc settings](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Multidoc)?

I see many people tempted to use the xr package, but Lyx does not seem to communicate well with it.  (Doesn't create aux files and requires [hacky solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39772/using-the-xr-package-in-lyx-for-cross-referencing-an-external-lyx-document)).

All of the questions I am seeing asked about this topic are over 5-15 years old with no updates, so I think this is time to ask the question again, even if it has a decade-old duplicate.